# Showing that a diagram commutes in the most economical way

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory

Suppose that one had to consider (co)cones on a complicated diagram, with many arrows and objects and that one wished to prove that one of them is final/initial.

Given another (co)cone, one would construct a unique morphism such that the whole diagram commutes. Of course, one could always check commutativity for all "subdiagrams", but I assume this is far from necessary in most cases.

For example, for (co)cartesian squares, one only needs to show that *two* triangles commute.

In general, given a diagram, how would one determine the smallest number of equalities to check in order to show that it commutes?

Comment: If the index category of the diagram has a generating set $S$ of morphisms (i.e. every morphism of the index category is a composition of morphisms in $S$), then you just need to check commutativity for those morphisms in $S$. But searching for the smallest generating set $S$ can be hard (I am not aware of any algorithm).

Comment: Ah, indeed. This is what I needed to convince myself of. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In general, without making further assumptions on the category in question, there are no shortcuts: take any 2 objects then any two connecting paths must be equal.

Nevertheless...you can somewhat optimize this procedure by considering first pairs of objects joint by multiple - non intersecting - paths. Non intersecting paths are paths which have only the starting and end objects in common, and nothing in between.
When you have k non intersecting paths joining 2 objects, then you need k-1 eqs. Once you have considered all such pairs of objects joint by multiple - non intersecting - paths, all other pairs are joint by intersecting paths - whose subpaths have been already considered and equated - plus maybe other non intersecting paths. You then simply add one more equation for each of these extra non intersecting path, and you are done.
In short: start with the shortest parallel paths first.

I hope I have been clear enough, otherwise I will draw a picture.

Comment: I don't think this is a proper answer.
If you have a directed $P_5$ $v_1v_2v_3v_4v_5$ and a directed $P_5$ $v_1w_2v_3w_4v_5$,
then the answer 'for any two objects any two connecting paths must be equal' is true,
but it does not help a lot.
The total number of paths between objects is $8$, but only you need to check 2 equalities.

Comment: @LeenDroogendijk What is a "directed $P_5$...." ? In any case, you (might) have a special category, but the question is very clear, in the last paragraph it says:"In general, given a diagram....", so your (or any other) special example is not relevant to the OP.

Comment: we disagree, but we have the OP as arbiter. A directed $P_5$ is a path with 5 nodes. I wanted to describe a diagram with two diamonds joined 'in the middle' without drawing it.

Comment: It would have surprised me if there was a general criterion. I am wondering if anyone has ever tried to answer the question, maybe with mild hypotheses. It seems to me that this is a graph theory question and I don't know much about that.

Comment: @R.N.  I added an optimization procedure, perhaps this is what you were looking for

Comment: @R.N. It is a generalization of the situation depicted by Pece in his comment above